# Type clash when trying to write a function over a product type

Tags: sml, ml

I have the following code in Standard ML:

```
datatype a = a;
val x = a;
val y:a = a;
val z = a;

fun fa a = a;

fun not' x = case x of
    true => false
  | false => true;

fun fst (a,b) = a;
fun snd (a,b) = b;
```

My function over a sum type (`not'`) works just fine, but when I try to use my function over a product type (`fst`), it gives me this error:

```
- fst (1,2);
! Toplevel input:
! fst (1,2);
!      ^
! Type clash: expression of type
!   int
! cannot have type
!   a
-
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bere more aware of variable names and scoping.

What is happening is that you have declared a datatype with a type constructor `a` and a value constructor `a`. Then, you late use `a` as an argument in your `fst` and `snd` functions, which then means you are matching for that value constructor `a` of the datatype. Probably not what you intended.

A quick fix is just to change the variable names used in the two functions

```
fun fst (x, y) = x;
fun snd (x, y) = y;

- fst(1,2);
val it = 1 : int
```

Normally the problem would have been easily seen from the types, however as you have chosen a rather unfortunate name to use, the original type of your functions were

```
val fst = fn : a * 'a -> a
val snd = fn : a * 'a -> 'a
```

but when the functions are fixed to not reference the datatype a, they will have a `'a` instead

```
val fst = fn : 'a * 'b -> 'a
val snd = fn : 'a * 'b -> 'b
```

It is generally considered good style to start with a capital letter for value constructors and all lower case for type constructors. One example is the option datatype, which however uses all capital letters for the value constructors (some other languages even enforce this)

```
datatype 'a option = NONE 
                   | SOME of 'a
```

The whole think may make more sense if we separate the names used for type and value, and call it something else than 'a', as that is also used as part of the "first" polymorphic type variable (i.e., most interpreters starts with `'a`).

```
datatype foo = Bar;
val x = Bar;
val y:foo = Bar;
val z = Bar;

fun fa Bar = Bar;
```